# msbuild not creating artifacts in teamcity

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I'm setting up a nightly build for continuous integration within TeamCity. I wanted to create an artifact dependency on the last complete build. But I notice that I have no artifacts created in my project. I'm building using MS build.

Comment: Did you define the Artifact Paths on the Build Configuration? Also did you check in the agent directory if there are files on the defined path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify what files you are interested in TeamCity saving as artifacts. This is done by changing the Artifact Path under General Settings when you edit the configuration.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Build+Artifact

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, no artifacts can be seen in the TeamCity Data Directory, as in it looks like MSBuild is not even building my installer for me?

Comment: In version 2017.1.4 at least, if you don't gave an Artifact Dependency then that artifact is cleaned